# Table View don't bounce

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

My question is :

Why when I build and run the **Table View created** with different rows **don't bounce**, although I selected the checkbox Bounces and Bounce Vertically in Xcode 6 ?

Comment: Have you got any code to examine?

Comment: Yes, of course. But the table's view bouncing in general depends only on the Bounces and Bounce Vertically or code too ?

Answer (score 1):

By default `UIScrollView`, which is a superclass of `UITableView` won't bounce if the content fits within its bounds i.e. if the rows fit within table's bounds. 
To alter this behaviour you can set [`alwaysBounceVertical`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619383-alwaysbouncevertical) property to `true`.

> **var alwaysBounceVertical: Bool { get set }**
>
> If this property is set to true and bounces is true, vertical dragging
>   is allowed even if the content is smaller than the bounds of the
>   scroll view. The default value is false.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

[eventTable setBounces:NO];
(OR)In Storyboard untick the Bounces.